# can I still making application for iPhone 4s or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, 32bit-64bit

I have an iPhone app in swift 3 - recently I heard that the apple company will remove 32 bit apps in the app store besides iPhone 4s doesn't support 64 bit apps - so does it means I have to ignore iPhone 4s in my app or not? because I have to build this app 32 bit and as apple said the 32 bit apps will be removed from app store so my question is that next year the developers can't build apps for iphone4s or not?

Comment: From a deleted post: "Check out this link. It may helps you":  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7991922?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: thats true So now the developers can make 64 and 32 bit for iPhones and only 32 bit app will remove and doesn't accept from app store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 11 will only support 64-bit apps.

If your app has a Deployment Target of iOS 11 or later then your app will only work in 64-bit mode and of course only on iOS 11 or later devices.

If your app has a Deployment Target of something earlier than iOS 11 then your app should support both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. And such an app will run on both 32-bit devices and 64-bit devices as the long as the device's iOS version isn't older than your app's Deployment Target.

The iPhone 4s only supports up to iOS 9.3.5. If you wish to support this device then your app's Deployment Target must be iOS 9.3 or earlier. And your app must support both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. Then your app will work just fine on the older devices and it will work with iOS 11 and 64-bit devices.

So yes, you can still support the iPhone 4s.

The problem is with old apps that haven't been updated with 64-bit support. Such old apps will not run under iOS 11.

Comment: But the apple company said that they will remove 32 bit apps so if they remove 32 bit apps from app store they won't let developer to submit 32 bit apps to app store

Comment: 1) Provide a link about this claim. 2) You can definitely submit apps that support both 64 and 32-bit, just not 32-bit only apps.

Comment: so you mean apple will still let developers to submit 32-bit and 64-bit apps and 64-bit apps to app store and the only thing that they won't let is just 32-bit apps ?

Comment: That's my understanding. I have apps that support iOS 8 and later. The app supports both 32 and 64 bit devices. It would be terrible if Apple suddenly disallowed us to update our apps to keep supporting both new and old devices. That would make a lot of users very unhappy.